# Present tense in reported past

Tags: verb-agreement

My friend said" Your child is beautiful". Can I report this statement as 'My friend  told me that my child is beautiful' or '.... my child was beautiful' for the sake of grammer rule ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reported / indirect speech - why no backshift](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477373/reported-indirect-speech-why-no-backshift)

Answer (score -1):

"Your child is beautiful" means your child is currently beautiful.

My child was beautiful **is** past tense, however it means that your child **used to be** beautiful.

You can say "My friend told me that my child is beautiful", because your child still is beautiful, but your friend already said so.