# Reported speech with an event before another in the past

Tags: past-tense, indirect-speech, rules

> He said that before people built roads, they travelled on the river.

The original statement before being reported, as I understand it, should be:

> Before people built roads, they travelled on the river.

Why don't we change tense in this example e.g past perfect? I know the above to be correct but am trying to explain it to students. :)

This is an example in a book we are using but this contradicts, or rather evades the rules the book has taught, and want to clear any confusion/give students a rule they can follow for statements like this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reported / indirect speech – why no backshift](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/477373/reported-indirect-speech-why-no-backshift) " 'Tense'  simplification" where the sequence of events remains clear. And 'He said that before people had built roads, they had had travelled on the river' to show a double-backward positioning of events isn't acceptable even to the most fastidious logician.

Comment: The sequence of events is conveyed by "before". This is the word that renders the perfect redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The past perfect is not appropriate in this case because travelling on the river was an habitual practice rather than a single event. If we were talking about single events then the past perfect would be indicated.

For instance "Before King Harold lost the battle against the Normans at Hastings he *had* defeated the Vikings at Stamford Bridge."

The past perfect is indicated here, not only because the battles of Stamford Bridge and Hastings were single events but because they were close enough in time that fighting at Stamford Bridge then marching nearly 300 miles south before facing the Normans would, almost certainly, have affected the fighting capability of  Harold's army.

Comment: You might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "before".

Comment: @BillJ You could, but I don't think that it would invalidate my answer. I can't think of a way of using the past perfect to discuss Stamford Bridge and Senlac without also using "before" or some other indication of the older past.

Answer (score 0):

> *He said that before people built roads, they travelled / had travelled on the river.*

You might say that the perfect is redundant here because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "before".